# ubuntu 20.04 - wireless not working for intel AX1650i (lenovo thinkpad)

Tags: wireless, 20.04, lenovo, iwlwifi

Kernel version is 5.9.12-050912-generic Below two images that I think show that some firmware/driver is missing, but couldn't manage to get it to work.

[image]

[image]

Also there are no blocks:

```
nico@nico:/usr/lib/firmware$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Does somebody knows how to fix this?

[EDIT]

```
nico@nico:/usr/lib/firmware$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
lspci: Unable to load libkmod resources: error -12
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW) [8086:34f0] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW) [8086:0000]
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:34e8] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [17aa:3852]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
--
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3852]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [17aa:3852]
```

[EDIT 2]
This command has  a longer output, which is just the same but with a different code before `ucode`

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl
[    9.032170] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)3.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.032177] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)2.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.032184] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)1.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.032192] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for (efault)0.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.032192] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
[    9.032214] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: (efault)0
[    9.032235] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: (efault)128
[    9.032255] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

Comment: Network UNCLAIMED means there is no driver, please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I edited the question

Comment: I edited the title, it is in fact Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Pleasee edit your question t show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question with the result

Comment: I have never seen this: "spci: Unable to load libkmod resources: error -12" and I have never seen this: "Direct firmware load for (efault)0.ucode failed with error -2" Please explain the steps, giving a link, if possible, to the method used to install your 5.9-xx kernel version. I suspect that you missed a step or a step has gone wrong. Can you reboot into the default 20.04 kernel at the GRUB menu and does the `dmesg | grep iwl` read any better?